# How do I cache Python variables in Google Colab

Tags: python, caching, google-colaboratory

After a period of inactivity, my Google Colab variables are lost and I have to recompute them. I know I can work around it with

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive/')
%cd '/content/drive/My Drive/path/to/my/project/folder'
```

and then use `numpy.save`, `torch.utils.checkpoint` or `tf.train.Checkpoint` which will save it to Google Drive if my variable is in one of these formats.

Is there a way to cache *any* Python variable on Colab (i.e. not be bound to a specific data science framework or format)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [cache-magic](https://pypi.org/project/cache-magic/) package with a symbolic link to your Drive folder.

Make the following your first cell in Colab and always run it first (replace `path/to/my/project/folder` with your Drive project folder):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd '/content/drive/My Drive/path/to/my/project/folder'

!pip install cache-magic
import cache_magic
!mkdir .cache
!ln -s '/content/drive/My Drive/path/to/my/project/folder/.cache' /content/.cache
```

Now when you have some long computation:

```
bigVariable = longComputation()
```

you replace it with

```
%cache bigVariable = longComputation()
```

and it will be reloaded from cache if it was computed before!

Your cache lives in a folder named `.cache` inside your project folder.